# MS Access: Bringing data with a lookup?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a part number and an abbreviation in separate fields. In a separate table, I want to lookup the part number, and have it bring the abbreviation. I have the part number lookup working, then I tried to add the abbreviation to the quire, but it limits the results to only part numbers that have an abbreviation. When I try to change the join type, it gives me outer join warnings...

Sorry it took me a day to respond, and that I didn't explain it better. Here is additional info:

I have the following tables with the following fields:

1756_PN(ID, 1756_PN, Description, Abrev)

That is sort of my bill of materials. However, I have many of these items, in different configurations. My table that calls apon the above bill of materials is called "Cards", with these fields:

Cards(ID, PLC, Rack, Slot, AB_Series, 1756_PN)

The last field (1756_PN) is a lookup to the first field. It allows me to pick which type of item I have.

I do a query that involves all the fields from Cards, and it looks fine. However, I add "Abrev" from the 1st table, and it either duplicates all the rows with all the different possible types of cards "1756_ID" or it only includes the cards that have been assigned a card type "1756_ID", depending on what type of join I have used (under "relationships").

All I want to do is bring the abbreviation, when I select a card type. These are both columns in the first table...

I have tried breaking the first table into smaller tables, that were linked by part number (1756_PN), but that just made things worse...

It seems so simple, but I can't make it work...

Comment: please saw your code!!

Comment: You need to show the code that you are using.  You haven't provided enough information to allow a good answer.  Also, you mention warnings here, but don't say what they are.

Comment: Show the table design, some example data, the query you are currently using, and what you are trying to achieve / what the expected outcome is

Comment: Sorry it took me a day to respond, and that I didn't explain it better. I have added additional info above. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the stupid question. Perhaps explaining it made me re-check things I thought I tried a 100 times...

I think this got it:

```
SELECT Cards.*, [1756_PN].Abrev
FROM 1756_PN RIGHT JOIN Cards ON [1756_PN].ID = Cards.[1756_PN];
```

I don't know why it wasn't working before... I re-installed access, and would like to blame the computer, but it was probably me...

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer today. If you are bored, you can post your (copy and paste is fine) and I will accept answer.